# HTTP post from android to PHP not working

Tags: php, android

I am trying to get a Android device to send some information to a local host. I believe I have the Android sending the information, but my PHP code is not accepting or not displaying the code. I have attached my code, is there something I have missed? I am running wamp server also, and have put the permissions into the manifest.

Java Code: #

```
HttpPost httppost;

    HttpClient httpclient;

    // List with arameters and their values
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;

    String serverResponsePhrase;
    int serverStatusCode;
    String bytesSent;
    String serverURL = "http://10.0.2.2/test/index.php";


    httppost = new HttpPost(serverURL);
    httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);

    // Adding parameters to send to the HTTP server.
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("parameterName1", "git"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("parameterName2", "git"));

    // Send POST message with given parameters to the HTTP server.
    try {
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(20);

        int current = 0;
        while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
            baf.append((byte) current);
        }

        bytesSent = new String(baf.toByteArray());

        // Response from the server
        serverResponsePhrase = response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase();
        serverStatusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        System.out.println("COMPLETE");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Exception handling
        System.out.println("Problem is " + e.toString());
    }
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
echo "param1 value: ".$_POST['parameterName1']."\n";
echo "param2 value: ".$_POST['parameterName2']."\n";
?>
```

I also tried this code, but it did not work with my PHP

```
HttpPost httppost;

    HttpClient httpclient;

    // List with arameters and their values
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;

    String serverResponsePhrase;
    int serverStatusCode;
    String bytesSent;
    String serverURL = "http://10.0.2.2/test/index.php";


    httppost = new HttpPost(serverURL);
    httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);

    // Adding parameters to send to the HTTP server.
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("'parameterName1'", "git"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("'parameterName2'", "git"));

    // Send POST message with given parameters to the HTTP server.
    try {
        HttpEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs);

        httppost.addHeader(entity.getContentType());
        httppost.setEntity(entity);


        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(20);

        int current = 0;
        while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
            baf.append((byte) current);
        }

        bytesSent = new String(baf.toByteArray());

        // Response from the server
        serverResponsePhrase = response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase();
        serverStatusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        System.out.println("response" + response.toString());
        System.out.println("COMPLETE");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Exception handling
        System.out.println("Problem is " + e.toString());
    }
```

Comment: Easy to confirm of the Android code is working: just look at the server's access log to see if a POST request comes in. If you don't get that, then the Android side of things isn't working right/at all.

Comment: I'm running a wamp local server. It will sound stupid but how do I check on there?

Comment: No idea about wamp. Check apache's httpd.conf and look for the "CustomLog" option.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 - - [21/Sep/2011:16:37:12 +0100] "POST /test/index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 221                                                                                   I found that, so I assume Android is working, then why is my PHP not?

Comment: Since the hit got to apache, and your code is simple enough that I can't see it failing (even if android's not posting any data, the script will still output a bit of text), I'd suggest looking at the response handlers in android. the response.whatever() calls.

Comment: Nothing displays on my PHP page. Just "param1 value: " etc. It seems that my PHP code will not display the POST.

Comment: More likely that android's not sending the data properly. PHP will display whatever it's sent.

Comment: I just changed the code, I will edit the original problem, as this code I found on stack overflow and works, but is not working with my php

Comment: It's highly unlikely to be a PHP problem.

Comment: I checked the response as you said with android. This was the response message to string from android.  09-21 16:00:47.262: INFO/System.out(733): org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@44f8adf0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the `Content-Type` HTTP header is getting set.  Try replacing

```
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

with this

```
HttpEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs);

httppost.addHeader(entity.getContentType());
httppost.setEntity(entity);
```

---

Also, instead of `response.toString()`, try `EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity())` if you want to see the body of the response

Comment: It seems to send from Android, I think it's an issue with PHP not recieving it, I got this from the logs after implementing your code 127.0.0.1 - - [21/Sep/2011:16:38:16 +0100] "GET /test/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2090
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Sep/2011:16:38:47 +0100] "GET /test/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2090
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Sep/2011:16:40:40 +0100] "POST /test/index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 221

Comment: Can you tell us what you get from `EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity())` instead of `response.toString()`?

Comment: 09-21 16:25:28.382: INFO/System.out(1032): Problem is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content has been consumed
  Obviously this is the problem! What does it mean though?

Comment: I managed to fix that, it was a double up on using response.getEntity().getContent(); however it still does not display on my PHP page on my wamp server. However in my system,out.print it seems to be working on the android (in the log cat) just not showing on the index.php in firefox

Comment: What steps are you taking to get to `index.php` in Firefox?

Comment: Solved. It was a wamp issue. I just had to reinstall.